# HTML 5 video recording and storing a stream

Tags: javascript, html

Using Html 5 I want to record video and save the stream into a local file. Given below is the code. In a button click it already invokes the camera and captures the video in the 'VIDEO' tag of HTML. Can I store the stream into a local file? Or can I store it as MP4 file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function enter() {

    if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
       navigator.myGetMedia=navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
       navigator.myGetMedia({video: true}, connect, error); 
    } 
    else {
       alert("NO");
    }

    function connect(stream) {

        var video = document.getElementById("my_video");
            video.src = window.URL ? window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
            video.play();

        var canvas = document.getElementById("c"); 
    }

    function error(e) { console.log(e); }

}

</script>

</head>    
<body>
    <canvas width="640" height="480" id="c"></canvas>
    <input type="button" value="RECORD" onClick="enter()"/>
    <input type="button" value="SAVE" />
    <video id="my_video" width="640" height="480"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to save the stream upon a save button click.

Answer (score 46):

**RecordRTC: WebRTC audio/video recording**

https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC

- Audio recording both for Chrome and Firefox
- Video/Gif recording for Chrome; (Firefox has a little bit issues, will be recovered soon)

Demo : https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

---

**Creating .webm video from getUserMedia()**

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia

Demo : http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/getusermedia/record-user-webm.html

---

**Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5**

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Good links, interesting solutions. But note that these are still workarounds that rely on taking snapshots of canvas elements and encoding the frames one-by-one with whammy.

Comment: it is muted in chrome and video not supported in firfox
how can i record my sound in chrome and video in firfox

Comment: Is anyone else experiencing Gill's issue? Would like to know before I try these solutions.

Comment: This says nothing about actually saving anything

Answer (score 21):

[MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) is the solution you are looking for,

Firefox has been supporting it for some time now, and the buzz is is Chrome is gonna  implement it in its next release (Chrome 48), but guess you still might need to enable the experimental flag, apparently the flag won't be need from Chrome version 49, for more info check out this [Chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=261321).

Meanwhile, a sample of how to do it in Firefox:

```js
var video, reqBtn, startBtn, stopBtn, ul, stream, recorder;
video = document.getElementById('video');
reqBtn = document.getElementById('request');
startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');
ul = document.getElementById('ul');
reqBtn.onclick = requestVideo;
startBtn.onclick = startRecording;
stopBtn.onclick = stopRecording;
startBtn.disabled = true;
ul.style.display = 'none';
stopBtn.disabled = true;

function requestVideo() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true
    })
    .then(stm => {
      stream = stm;
      reqBtn.style.display = 'none';
      startBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }).catch(e => console.error(e));
}

function startRecording() {
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
    mimeType: 'video/mp4'
  });
  recorder.start();
  stopBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  startBtn.disabled = true;
}


function stopRecording() {
  recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
    ul.style.display = 'block';
    var a = document.createElement('a'),
      li = document.createElement('li');
    a.download = ['video_', (new Date() + '').slice(4, 28), '.webm'].join('');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
    a.textContent = a.download;
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  };
  recorder.stop();
  startBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  stopBtn.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <button id='request'>
    Request Camera
  </button>
  <button id='start'>
    Start Recording
  </button>
  <button id='stop'>
    Stop Recording
  </button>
  <ul id='ul'>
    Downloads List:
  </ul>

</div>
<video id='video' autoplay></video>
```

Comment: @jim, it is probably a https issue, can ou try out https://mido22.github.io/MediaRecorder-sample/

Comment: Any idea why I get "NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported" on line 47, which is `recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType:'video/mp4' });`?

Comment: Firefox 62 says `MediaStreamError{name: "NotFoundError",message:"The object can not be found here."}` on my HTTPS localhost.

Comment: Does it support on safari?

Comment: video.srcObject = stm instead of video.src, refer below article https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2018/url-createobjecturl-no-longer-accepts-mediastream-as-argument/

Answer (score 10):

Currently there is no production ready **HTML5 only** solution for recording video over the web. The current available solutions are as follows:

**HTML Media Capture**

Works on mobile devices and uses the OS' video capture app to capture video and upload/POST it to a web server. You will get **.mov** files on iOS (these are unplayable on Android I've tried) and **.mp4 and .3gp** on Android. At least the codecs will be the same: H.264 for video and AAC for audio in 99% of the devices.

[image: HTML Media Capture]

Image courtesy of https://blog.addpipe.com/the-new-video-recording-prompt-for-media-capture-in-ios9/

**Flash and a media server on desktop**.

Video recording in Flash works like this: audio and video data is captured from the webcam and microphone, it's encoded using Sorenson Spark or H.264 (video) and Nellymoser Asao or Speex (audio) then it's streamed (rtmp) to a media server (Red5, AMS, Wowza) where it is saved in **.flv or .f4v** files.

**The MediaStream Recording proposal**

> The MediaStream Recording is a proposal by the the Media Capture Task Force (a joint task force between the WebRTC and Device APIs working groups) for a JS API who's purpose is to make basic video recording in the browser very simple.

Not supported by major browsers. When it'll get implemented (if it will) you will most probably end up with different filetypes (at least .ogg and .webm) and audio/video codecs depending on the browser.

**Commercial solutions**

There are a few saas and software  solutions out there that will handle some or all of the above including addpipe.com, HDFVR, Nimbb and Cameratag.

Further reading:

- [HTML Media Capture video recording prompts in iOS9](https://blog.addpipe.com/the-new-video-recording-prompt-for-media-capture-in-ios9/)
- [HTML5 Video Recording](https://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording) covers both  HTML Media Capture and MediaStream Recording.
- [Pipe](http://addpipe.com) is a saas for video recording that also handles the final conversion to .mp4

Answer (score 6):

Here is an elegant library that records video in all supported browsers and supports uploading:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-record

Comment: This article on medium even provides much detailed description of advanced features like saving to a local file, to the server, etc. https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/record-audio-video-image-and-gif-from-browser-using-videojs-record-2249fcc6ea9e

Answer (score 5):

The followin example shows how to capture and process video frames in HTML5:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Capturing & Processing Video in HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Camera Preview</h2>
        <video id="cameraPreview" width="240" height="180" autoplay></video>
        <p>
            <button id="startButton" onclick="startCapture();">Start Capture</button>
            <button id="stopButton" onclick="stopCapture();">Stop Capture</button>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Processing Preview</h2>
        <canvas id="processingPreview" width="240" height="180"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Recording Preview</h2>
        <video id="recordingPreview" width="240" height="180" autoplay controls></video>
        <p>
            <a id="downloadButton">Download</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script>

    const ROI_X = 250;
    const ROI_Y = 150;
    const ROI_WIDTH = 240;
    const ROI_HEIGHT = 180;
    
    const FPS = 25;
    
    let cameraStream = null;
    let processingStream = null;
    let mediaRecorder = null;
    let mediaChunks = null;
    let processingPreviewIntervalId = null;

    function processFrame() {
        let cameraPreview = document.getElementById("cameraPreview");
        
        processingPreview
            .getContext('2d')
            .drawImage(cameraPreview, ROI_X, ROI_Y, ROI_WIDTH, ROI_HEIGHT, 0, 0, ROI_WIDTH, ROI_HEIGHT);
    }
    
    function generateRecordingPreview() {
        let mediaBlob = new Blob(mediaChunks, { type: "video/webm" });
        let mediaBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(mediaBlob);
        
        let recordingPreview = document.getElementById("recordingPreview");
        recordingPreview.src = mediaBlobUrl;

        let downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton");
        downloadButton.href = mediaBlobUrl;
        downloadButton.download = "RecordedVideo.webm";
    }
        
    function startCapture() {
        const constraints = { video: true, audio: false };
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((stream) => {
            cameraStream = stream;
            
            let processingPreview = document.getElementById("processingPreview");
            processingStream = processingPreview.captureStream(FPS);
            
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(processingStream);
            mediaChunks = []
            
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
                mediaChunks.push(event.data);
                if(mediaRecorder.state == "inactive") {
                    generateRecordingPreview();
                }
            };
            
            mediaRecorder.start();
            
            let cameraPreview = document.getElementById("cameraPreview");
            cameraPreview.srcObject = stream;
        
            processingPreviewIntervalId = setInterval(processFrame, 1000 / FPS);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            alert("No media device found!");
        });
    };
    
    function stopCapture() {
        if(cameraStream != null) {
            cameraStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                track.stop();
            });
        }
        
        if(processingStream != null) {
            processingStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                track.stop();
            });
        }
        
        if(mediaRecorder != null) {
            if(mediaRecorder.state == "recording") {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
            }
        }
        
        if(processingPreviewIntervalId != null) {
            clearInterval(processingPreviewIntervalId);
            processingPreviewIntervalId = null;
        }
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```