# Webcam Video Capturing Software

Tags: video, web, capture, recording

I was searching the web, but I can't find open source video recording solution similar to the following audio recording related solution:

https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

What I need is JavaScript (flash wrapped) solution that will record video (2 minutes for example) and save that video on my server. There are commercial solutions that require streaming servers (HDFVR) or solutions that host the videos on their own servers (NIMBB).

None of these are acceptable solutions because the videos must be saved as MP4 files on our own servers and the code that saves the captured video must reside on the application server itself.

Comment: On the other hand of RecordRTC, you can even use [MediaStreamRecorder.js](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder): It supports "record and return blob(s) after specific intervals".

Comment: [HDFVR](https://hdfvr.com) can link to FFmpeg to convert recorded videos to .mp4 + you can get the as3/fla sources

Answer (score 0):

For only javascript, you can use [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC). RecordRTC is MIT licensed on github.

Examples: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Check this other question:
[HTML 5 video recording and storing a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509385/html-5-video-recording-and-storing-a-stream)