# How to record video in Ionic 2 application in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am trying to capture video in Ionic 2 app using TypeScript. Taking a picture is straight forward and seems easy.

```
    Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        targetWidth: 1000
    }).then((imageData) => {
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; 
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

What changes do I need to make in order to capture video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML 5 video recording and storing a stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509385/html-5-video-recording-and-storing-a-stream)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't take a look at the code of this app *yet*, but you can take a look at the plugins used there and how they work (working on nexus 7 2013).

https://github.com/rossmartin/video-editor-ionic2

These are the required plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 
cordova-plugin-device 
cordova-plugin-media-capture 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard.git 
cordova-plugin-statusbar 
cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog 
cordova-plugin-instagram-assets-picker 
cordova-plugin-video-editor
```

Comment: I have already seen this answer for another question. My question is how to do it in typescript app without ngZone?

Comment: Did you take a look at that link? Did you write some code that we can take a look?

Comment: I tried using that code. It says Property 'device' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

Comment: It needs to be executed on a real device, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: of course yes. Typescript is not being compiled in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the Media capture plugin `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture` then install the angular typescript wrapper `npm install --save @ionic-native/media-capture`

```
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile } from '@ionic-native/media-capture'; // import the angular typescript classes from the installed wrapper

@Component(...)

export class Test{
   constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture) { } // inject the services in the constructor

   this.mediaCapture.captureVideo().then((data: MediaFile[]) =>{
     console.log(data) // data is the captured video file object 
 });
}
```

Check the Ionic Doc for this plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/