# Make a video call for web browser

Tags: javascript

Can I record stream video and save on a Apache server,
after send by AJAX and take a video call?

```
'use strict';
     const mediaStreamConstraints = {
  video: true,
};

const localVideo = document.querySelector('video');

let localStream;

function gotLocalMediaStream(mediaStream) {
  localStream = mediaStream;
  localVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
}

function handleLocalMediaStreamError(error) {
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaStreamConstraints)
  .then(gotLocalMediaStream).catch(handleLocalMediaStreamError);
console.log(handleLocalMediaStreamError);
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... are you trying to record a video, or initiate a two-way video call?

Comment: Sorry for this, I'm trying send video stream by AJAX / PHP for video call.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509385/html-5-video-recording-and-storing-a-stream/18509824

Comment: I would think you'd need webRTC for this kind of thing. I doubt Ajax would be a good solution